# How to count grid row size when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to set visibility of a div according to the size of grid which are on the same page; grid is loaded when the page is opened How can I do this ? I wrote following js but took errors.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false"
        CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed"
        EmptyDataText="Kayıtlı İş Tecrübesi Bilgisi Bulunmamaktadır."
        OnRowDataBound="OnGridRowDataBound" OnRowCommand="OnGridRowCommand" OnRowCreated="OnGridRowCreated"
        DataKeyNames="KAYITNO"
        RowStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-grid-row" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-grid-row-alternate" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-grid-row-selected">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-data-key">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="dataKeyButton" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"KAYITNO") %>' Visible="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-data-command" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small btn-info">Seç</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="ozgecmis-data-text">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#FormatData(Eval("ISYERIUNVAN"),Eval("GIRISTARIHSTR"),Eval("CIKISTARIHSTR"),Eval("ISTANIMI"),Eval("SEKTOR"),Eval("POZISYON"),Eval("MESLEK"),Eval("MESLEKUZMANLIK")) %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>



    $( "#grid" ).on( "load", function() {
        var gridView = document.getElementById("<%=grid.ClientID %>");
        var rows = gridView.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        if (rows.length>0){
            isTecrubesiBos.Visible = true;
        }
        } );
```

Comment: <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group" id="isTecrubesiBos" Visible="false" style="background-color:red;"  runat="server" >Tecrübe Bilgisi Giriniz !</div></div> it is in the aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grid` and `div` both are server side control, they change there `id` when page load. So after page load means `document.ready` show your `div` via `document.getElementById("<%= isTecrubesiBos.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';` .

Example:

```
$(function() {
  var gridView = document.getElementById("<%= grid.ClientID %>").rows.length;
  if (gridView.length > 0) {
     document.getElementById("<%= isTecrubesiBos.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

If any case, need to hide `div` :

```
 document.getElementById("<%= isTecrubesiBos.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do that check WHEN you load the grid and set its data source.

So, say this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Information" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn" 
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:TextBox ID="isTecrubesiBos" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And now in code, you can do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim rstData As DataTable
    rstData = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    isTecrubesiBos.Visible = rstData.Rows.Count > 0
    GHotels.DataSource = rstData
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

So, we get/see this:

[image]

So, since the data source has a row count > 0, then we at that point in time are free to set the visible of the text box in question.

Comment: Thank you Albert but I cannot do this in pageload because of performance constraints. I want to do this with js

Comment: How would doing this on page load be a performance consideration when the page NOT even having been send to the client side yet? using js is not going to effect the performance here, since the page not even reached the client side yet for any js code to even have run. You may want to do this client side for other reasons, but performance is not one of those reasons.

Comment: We use webform tech even we select from a combobox page load is called again. In page load we call db operations this causes performance problems because of our framework

Comment: Well, then that is database performance issue, and it as such is NOT going to be effected by the hide or show of one text box on a form. As I stated you may have reasons for trying to hide a simple text box client side (as opposed to server side code which HAS to run to fill out the gv). However, performance considerations are NOT part of that narrative and solution in regards to hiding some text box. So, that's a different and 100% separate narrative and goal to hide/show a text box vs that of pulling data and that of the performance of pulling that data. These are 2 rather separate issues.